# Celery: No result backend is configured

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to use **Celery** to asynchronously webscrape course registration info from a school university website. Ultimately, I want to build something where users are notified if a seat opens up in a specific course. **RabbitMQ** is my message broker. I am using **Django**, when running my server I am met with an error.

[image]

I don't know what I am missing but this is my first project using something like celery to query data asynchronously. If someone could be show me what i'm missing that would be greatly appreciated. Below is a screenshot of my RabbitMQ dashboard which I believe is running and configured with my project.

[image]
Below is my code

> settings

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost:5672'  # RabbitMQ broker URL
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://localhost:5672'
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from .forms import CourseRegistrationForm
from .tasks import scrape_course_data


def main(request):
    form = CourseRegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CourseRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            term = form.cleaned_data['semester']
            subj = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            crse = form.cleaned_data['course_number']

            classes_result = scrape_course_data.delay(term, subj, crse)
       
            classes = classes_result.get()  # Get the actual result

            print(classes)
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'classes':classes
            }
            return render(request, 'classes.html', context)
            
        else:
            form = CourseRegistrationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

> tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task, Celery
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

@shared_task
def scrape_course_data(term, subj, crse):
    print('SOUP')
    url=f'this is the url i am scraping from. no problems here'
    link=requests.get(url).text
    content=BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
    body=content.body
    table=body.find(class_='datadisplaytable')
    tble=table.contents[5:]   

    classes=[]

    for row in tble:
        if 'bs4.element.Tag' in str(type(row)):
            course=row.find_all('td')
        
            if len(course)>1:
                if course[2].text==subj:
                    clas={}
                    clas['subj']=course[2].text
                    clas['crse']=course[3].text
                    if course[0].text == 'C':
                        clas['availability']='Full'
                    else:
                        clas['availability']='Available'
                    clas['title']=course[6].text
                    clas['id']=course[1].text
                    clas['seats']=course[12].text
                    clas['seats_avail']=course[13].text
                    classes.append(clas)

    return classes
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using RabbitMQ for both Messaging and Results with Celery:**

1. **Configuration**:

   - Set your broker: `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost//'`
   - Use RabbitMQ for results: `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'`
2. **Fetching Task Results**:

   - Call task: `result = some_celery_task.delay(some_arg)`
   - Retrieve its result when ready: `result.result`
3. **Manage Result Storage**:

   - **Set Expiry**: Automatically remove results after a set time to save space:

     ```py
     CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600  # deletes results after 1 hour
     ```
   - **Ignore Results**: For tasks where results aren't needed:

     ```py
     @task(ignore_result=True)
     def some_task():
         ...
     ```
4. **Note**: Monitor RabbitMQ. Using it as a result backend may lead to many messages (results) stored, so manage and monitor accordingly.

---

With this configuration, you're leveraging RabbitMQ for both message brokering and result storage in Celery. Always keep an eye on RabbitMQ's queues to ensure optimal performance.

Comment: I followed your instructions yet still end up with a "No result backend is configured." Error.

Comment: Ensure that you're editing the correct configuration file, and your Django project is loading the Celery configurations from this file. Clear pyc files, etc.

Comment: Also ensure that Celery is initialized with Django settings.